# DoS attacks on ignite ports

Tags: ignite

The ignite I use is embedded,ignite uses two ports, When I was testing a dos attack on the port, ignite had java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory.

```
[2021-12-01 14:12:59,056][WARN ][0][0][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-4-#43%TcpCommunicationSpi%][ROOT][IgniteLoggerImp][88] Caught unhandled exception in NIO worker thread (restart the node). java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:695)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.register(GridNioServer.java:2672)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    [2021-12-01 14:12:59,057][WARN ][0][0][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0- 
  #39%TcpCommunicationSpi%][ROOT][IgniteLoggerImp][88] Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory]] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:695)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.register(GridNioServer.java:2672)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1910)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
```

How Do I Solve DoS Attacks on Ports?

Comment: Is this a problem?

Comment: Sort of, it's better to restrict the port usage with whitelisting IP addresses.

Comment: How do I configure a whitelisting IP addresses?

Comment: I was referring to a network/machines configuration like AWS, not Ignites'