# Why is the Ignite port listening not authenticated?

Tags: ignite

org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer#createSelector

```
// Create a new selector
        selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();

        if (addr != null) {
            // Create a new non-blocking server socket channel
            srvrCh = ServerSocketChannel.open();

            srvrCh.configureBlocking(false);

            if (sockRcvBuf > 0)
                srvrCh.socket().setReceiveBufferSize(sockRcvBuf);

            // Bind the server socket to the specified address and port
            srvrCh.socket().bind(addr);

            // Register the server socket channel, indicating an interest in
            // accepting new connections
            srvrCh.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        }

        return selector;
```

Why is the Ignite port listening not authenticated?
How can I set authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Two parts:

1. It has to open the connection so that it can be told what the credentials are. If they're not valid, Ignite will disconnect
2. Ignite can only authenticate thin-clients out-of-the-box. I have not checked the code, but this could be a server or thick-client code path

Comment: I can write a program that keeps creating connections, and ignite overflows.     Is this a problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70180069/dos-attacks-on-ignite-ports

Comment: I mean, it's not ideal but Ignite isn't really designed to be public-facing in the same way that, say, that web server is. You should probably configure your network so that unknown clients are not able to connect.

Comment: Ignite can also add MaxConnect as Tomcat and set a counter. If the counter exceeds the value, wait for several seconds.

Comment: If this is important to you, you can open a ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/). Note that if you want to authenticate thick-clients, there are commercial versions that do this.